# Triple-double quote v.s. Double quote

Tags: python, pep8, quote, docstring, pep

What is the preferred way to write Python doc string?

`"""` or `"`

In the book  [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/documenting_functions.html), the author provides the following example:

```
def buildConnectionString(params):
    """Build a connection string from a dictionary of parameters.

    Returns string."""
```

In another [chapter](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/index.html#fileinfo.divein), the author provides another example:

```
def stripnulls(data):
    "strip whitespace and nulls"
    return data.replace("\00", "").strip()
```

Both syntax work.  The only difference to me is that `"""` allows us to write multi-line doc.

Are there any differences other than that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the [PEP8 Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

- [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings) describes good docstring conventions. Note that most
  importantly, the """ that ends a multiline docstring should be on a
  line by itself, e.g.:

  ```
  """Return a foobang

  Optional plotz says to frobnicate the bizbaz first.
  """
  ```
- For one liner docstrings, it's okay to keep the closing """ on the
  same line.

[PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings) recommends using triple quotes, even for one-line docstrings:

- Triple quotes are used even though the string fits on one line. This
  makes it easy to later expand it.

Note that not even the Python standard library itself follows these recommendations consistently. For example,

- [abcoll.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/db9fe49069ed/Lib/collections/abc.py#l234)
- [ftplib.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/db9fe49069ed/Lib/ftplib.py#l75)
- [functools.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/db9fe49069ed/Lib/functools.py#l28)
- [inspect.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/db9fe49069ed/Lib/inspect.py#l360)

Comment: Sounds like the author of **Dive Into Python** have been using "not-so-good" syntax across the book --- Most ending """ in the examples are not on a separate line :-)

Comment: Follow the convention if you find it useful. But I'd rather not hold it against anyone for not following this particular convention. :)

Comment: Thanks, @unutbu. I like the book `Dive Into Python` a lot, and Mark Pilgrim explains things rather nicely.  As you pointed out, even Python standard library does not follow this convention strictly.  I guess this is one of those `nice-to-have` conventions.

Comment: The Python library is rather sloppy when it comes to *any* application of the styleguides.. :-)

Comment: I do not see the clause "and preferably preceded by a blank line" in PEP8, and the example is changed accordingly.

Comment: @JitseNiesen: Yes, the PEP8 recommendation has changed. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 10):

They're both strings, so there is no difference. The preferred style is triple double quotes ([PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)):

> For consistency, always use `"""triple double quotes"""` around docstrings.
>
> Use `r"""raw triple double quotes"""` if you use any backslashes in your docstrings. For Unicode docstrings, use `u"""Unicode triple-quoted strings"""`.

Comment: The `u` shouldn't be necessary in Python 3 where all strings are Unicode by default.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. If you are writing to a file, using triple quotes may be ideal, because you don't have to use "\n" in order to go a line down. Just make sure the quotes you start and end with are the same type(Double or Triple quotes). Here is a reliable resource if you have any more questions:

http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/strings.html

Comment: Any reason you: 1) give documentation to Python 1.5.1 (released in 1998)? 2) discourage OP from using different quotes? (I am asking, because you did not explain, while it will work: http://ideone.com/tID3uI).

Comment: @Tadeck - I for one find it very interesting to look at very old Python documentation. It's always super interesting to see how many Python's best ideas were already present before Python had even been seen by anyone other than Guido.

Comment: If that's the case, @ArtOfWarfare, it's a better answer if you give the context that the info here was established in that version and has not changed since.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **triple-double quotes** for **a long SQL query** to improve **the readability** and not to scroll right to see it as shown below:

```py
query = """
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM (SELECT * 
              FROM student  
              WHERE grade = 2 AND major = 'Computer Science' 
              FOR UPDATE) 
        AS result;
        """
```

And, if using **double quotes** for **the SQL query above**, **the readability** is worse and you will need to scroll right to see it as shown below:

```py
query = "SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM student WHERE grade = 2 AND major = 'Computer Science' FOR UPDATE) AS result;"
```

In addition, you can also use **triple-double quotes** for **a GraphQL query** as shown below:

```py
query = """
        {
            products(first: 5) {
                edges {
                    node {
                    id
                    handle
                    }
                }
            }
        }"""
```