# How would I ignore a single quotation mark within a string that interacts with my embedded quotation marks?

Tags: java, html

My problem is found here in my loop that displays the results from my SQL query in my java into HTML

I need to add an "add to cart" link with <a href='?id=*id*&name=*name* etc.> But the problem lies in that one of the results the name has a possesive as in "John's Smith".

This single quotation mark is ending my href link and not adding that into the *name* section of the link.

Any suggestions?

```
do {    
        
out.println("<tr><td class='col-md-1'> <a href='addcart.jsp?id="+rst.getString(1)+"&name="+rst.getString(2)+"&price="+rst.getString(4)+"'>Add to cart</a></td><td>"+rst.getString(2)+"</td><td>"+rst.getString(3)+"</td><td>"+rst.getString(4)+"</td></tr>");

} while (rst.next());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use double quote or even triple quote, more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643894/triple-double-quote-v-s-double-quote#:~:text=They're%20both%20strings%2C%20so,any%20backslashes%20in%20your%20docstrings.)

Comment: `<a href=\".....\"`

Comment: URLEncoding: `John%27s%20Smith`

Comment: By the way, if you have price as a URL parameter I'll definitely shop there and buy everything you have for `0.01`

Comment: @StephenP that's utterly mean and funny lol

Comment: @StephenP Hahah it is just for a school project learning SQL web programming. Just a sample site. But I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle arbitrary and unknown characters in your href is by using *URL Encoding*, then it won't matter which quotes you use (single or double) or how your quotes might be nested.

Java has a [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class specifically to do this.

Typically you'd use it on the query string if the rest of the url is known and fixed. I'd recommend building the query string, url encoding it, and *then* adding that to your output, something like:

```
final String query =
  "id=" + rst.getString(1) +
  "&name=" + rst.getString(2) +
  "&price=" + rst.getString(4);

out.println("<tr><td class='col-md-1'> <a href='addcart.jsp?" + 
            URLEncoder.encode(query) +
            "etc. the rest");
```

This [Guide to Java URL Encoding/Decoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-url-encoding-decoding) may be helpful.